# password attempts

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The password must have a length of 8 and be composed of lower case letters and/or numbers (letters and numbers can be repeated).

Suppose someone wants to access your online bank account.  How many passwords would they have to try before being able to log into your online bank account?

My answer:  $(26+10)^8$

Suppose you knew the last 6 chars/numbers of someone's password, how many passwords would you have to try before being able to log into their online bank account?

My answer:  $36 \times 36$

Thoughts please.   Thanks.

Comment: Actually, they'd only need to *try* $(26+10)^8 - 1$ passwords, because after that they *know* the last combination works.  But that's picking at the wording of the question, rather than answering it.

Comment: Your logic seems correct, and I see no flaw in it. Realistically though you should start with "password" and "12345678" and other words/patterns that might be more common.

Comment: Well, those numbers are the total number of possible passwords, but it's unlikely that someone would actually have to try all of those before guessing the password. Chances are they'd encounter it before they got through all of them. It's impossible really to answer the question as you've posed it, but we could answer the question "what is the expected value of how many passwords they would have to try?"